# Hovering over chart.js values in Meteor onRendered function causes chart axis shift

Tags: javascript, meteor, graph, chart.js

I have a chart.js bargraph inside self.autorun function that responds reactively to a dropdown selector. When I select a new entity from the dropdown and then hover over the values in the bargraph the y-axis jumps like this:

[image: Meteor chart.js axis and value jumping when hovering over values]

Dropdown code:

```
Template.Dropdown.events({
    "change #category-select": function (event) {
        var category = event.currentTarget.value;
        Session.set("chosenDairy", category)
       }
});
```

Bargraph code:

```
    Template.Bothdaily.onRendered(function () {
    Tracker.autorun(function(){
    //look up mongodb values
    //do some calculations

    //Begin Chart.js bargraph   
    var options = {
        //bargraph options
    };

    var data = {
        //bargraph data
    };

    var ctxtwo = document.getElementById("myBothDaily").getContext("2d");
    var myBarBothDaily = new Chart(ctxtwo).Bar(data, options);

    })//autorun

}); //onRendered
```

html code:

```
<template name="Bothdaily">
  <canvas id="myBothDaily" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</template>
```

I suspect this is because both values are present in the bargraph. I thought this might be fixed with a Tracker.afterflush() function but no luck.

Can you suggest how I might remove the y-axis shift when hovering over my reactive chart.js bargraph?

Comment: jittery chart axis may be a problem with chart.js as judged by comments here: https://forums.meteor.com/t/collection-not-available-onrendered-when-using-flow-router-solved/8105/6 "The chart is still jittery on mouse over and shows incorrect data but not as schizophrenic as it was with my code"

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a hovering issue with charts which is bringing back the data of old chart.

make `myBarBothDaily` variable global and bind it with the context of template and initialise it with null before the `Tracker.autorun()` block

```
this.myBarBothDaily = null
```

now inside autorun block, before instantiating your chart, destroy the data of previous chart by calling `destroy()` function of chart.js.

```
if(this.myBarBothDaily) {
   this.myBarBothDaily.destroy();
}
this.myBarBothDaily = new Chart(ctxtwo).Bar(data, options);
```

this should fix your issue.